# Training process stuck in a local minimum for neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on a neural network that's designed to identify patterns in a large dataset, but I'm running into an issue where the training process seems to be stuck in a local minimum. Despite trying a variety of different optimization algorithms and adjusting the learning rate, I can't seem to get the network to converge on a more optimal solution. Here's the code I'm using to train the network:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load dataset
data = np.load('data.npy')

# Split dataset into training and validation sets
train_data = data[:5000]
val_data = data[5000:]

# Define neural network architecture
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(data.shape[1],)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train model
history = model.fit(train_data[:, :-1], train_data[:, -1],
                    validation_data=(val_data[:, :-1], val_data[:, -1]),
                    batch_size=32,
                    epochs=100,
                    verbose=1)
```

I suspect that there might be an issue with the dataset itself, but I've tried normalizing and standardizing the data, as well as applying various preprocessing techniques, with no luck. Any insights or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You seem to have only 2 categories so do you have balanced training dataset? Your data are already normalized?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one source related to your problems (https://github.com/christianversloot/machine-learning-articles/blob/main/getting-out-of-loss-plateaus-by-adjusting-learning-rates.md). Have a look! May give you some ideas.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using different train/val splits? It could be something specific to the split you happen to have selected.